# Does evolving your buddy retain the amount of walking you have done thus far?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I make an Eevee my buddy and after walking 2km I then decide to evolve the Eevee, will the 2km of walking we've done together be retained or will it reset?

Comment: I want to say yes because it is the same Pokemon, but I will have to look for an official source.

Comment: @Vemonus: I'm of the same mind. Since I couldn't find a source off-hand, I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug that *actually does* reset your progress when you evolve.

According to this [site's report](http://pokemongoglobal.com/2016/09/14/something-need-know-evolving-buddy-pokemon/):

> When you walk your Pokemon and obtain enough Poke Candy to evolve them, your  Pokemon’s progress gets reset if you evolve them before receiving the reward. There’s numerous reports on this issue, however we are unsure if this is a flaw, or if this is supposed to be this way.

Photographic evidence:

[image]

It's worth noting that (based on the picture), the total distance does not reset. Only the current progress towards the next reward does.

Comment: That's... really dumb. Here's hoping it's a bug and it will be fixed.

Comment: @Ellesedil before or after they fix tracking? :P

Comment: Is this still a thing or did they fix it? I'm playing a lot less often nowadays.

Comment: @Ellesedil I'm about to evolve a Grimer, so I'll walk a bit and let you know

Comment: @Ellesedil can confirm it's still this behavior. Muk lost 0.3km.